# TypeError: unhashable type

Tags: python, json, list

Получаю данные в json:

```
"chestCycle": {
        "upcoming": [
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "gold",
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "gold",
            "silver"
        ],
```

Делаю перевод этих значений:

```
self.icons = {
        "silver": "Серебрянный сундук",
        "gold": "Золотой сундук",
        "superMagical": "Супер магический сундук",
        "magical": "Магический сундук",
        "legendary": "Легендарный сундук",
        "epic": "Эпический сундук",
        "giant": "Гиганский сундук",
    }
```

Пытаюсь вывести:

```
player = await client.get_player(text)
soobs = f"След сундуки: {self.icons[player.chestCycle.upcoming]}"
print(soobs)
```

Но выдает ошибку(

> ```
> soobs = f"След сундуки: {self.icons[player.chestCycle.upcoming]}"
> ```
>
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'BoxList'

Comment: Что у вас в player.chestCycle.upcoming?

Comment: "chestCycle": {
        "upcoming": [
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "gold",
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "silver",
            "gold",
            "silver"
        ],
        "superMagical": 521,
        "magical": 67,
        "legendary": 543,
        "epic": 451,
        "giant": 35
    },

Comment: и вот это все вы пытаетесь использовать в качестве ключа в словаре?

Comment: Я в этом еще нуб( Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку

Comment: Ну как бы в self.icons у вас ключи строки silver, gold и т.д., а вы в качестве ключа туда словарь передаете.

Comment: Понял, благодарю

Comment: Я все такие недоконца понял, если вам нетрудно можете 1 правельный пример сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь в Python - это (внешне) очень простая штука. У него просто есть ключи и сопоставленные им значения. Если на "вход" словаря подать ключ, то получим соответствующее этому ключу значение. Нельзя подать больше одного ключа (точнее можно, но ничего хорошего не получите - в лучшем случае `KeyError`). Нельзя подать на вход в качестве ключа нехешируемое (unhashable) значение (к которому нельзя применить функцию `hash()`) - получите ошибку `TypeError: unhashable type`. Словарь внутри работает как [хеш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) (очень рекомендую данную статью к изучению), отсюда требование, что к ключам должна быть применима стандартная питоновская хеш-функция.

Вы пытаетесь передать в словарь список ключей, причем не просто список, а список внутри какого-то контейнера (`BoxList`). Словарь не обладает искусственным интеллектом, и сам не поймет, что вы от него хотели, а будет просто считать, что вы передали в него такой ключ. Видимо переданный объект класса `BoxList` не является хешируемым объектом, поэтому получаете ошибку `TypeError: unhashable type`.

Чтобы получить из списка ключей список значений из словаря, то нужно циклом пройти по первоначальному списку, и каждый ключ подставить в словарь.

Пример, у вас есть список ключей и словарь:

```
upcoming = [
    "silver",
    "silver",
    "gold",
    "silver",
    "silver",
    "silver",
    "silver",
    "gold",
    "silver"
]

icons = {
    "silver": "Серебрянный сундук",
    "gold": "Золотой сундук",
    "superMagical": "Супер магический сундук",
    "magical": "Магический сундук",
    "legendary": "Легендарный сундук",
    "epic": "Эпический сундук",
    "giant": "Гиганский сундук",
}
```

По этому списку пройтись циклом, каждый ключ подставить в словарь:

```
print([icons[key] for key in upcoming])
# Вывод: ['Серебрянный сундук', 'Серебрянный сундук', 'Золотой сундук', 'Серебрянный сундук', 'Серебрянный сундук', 'Серебрянный сундук', 'Серебрянный сундук', 'Золотой сундук', 'Серебрянный сундук']
```

Человеку нужно показать не список строк (в квадратных скобках, каждая строка в кавычках), а просто перечисление сундуков. Для этого нужно этот список строк объединить в цельную строку через запятую с помощью метода `join()`:

```
print(', '.join(icons[key] for key in upcoming))
# Вывод: Серебрянный сундук, Серебрянный сундук, Золотой сундук, Серебрянный сундук, Серебрянный сундук, Серебрянный сундук, Серебрянный сундук, Золотой сундук, Серебрянный сундук
```

Ну и ваше сообщение будет формироваться примерно так:

```
soobs = "След сундуки: " + ', '.join(self.icons[key] for key in player.chestCycle.upcoming)
```

Это будет работать только если объект `BoxList` поддерживает итерацию по нему.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, я многое открыл для себя, удачи вам)